# Understanding a construction (para . contents) and continuing education

Tags: function, syntax, functional-programming, scheme, lisp

I've just started the Scheme Lisp learning and needed some illumination. I've hit a snippet at a site https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Types-and-the-Web.html that I haven't caught [(para . contents)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9R1X.png)

This hasn't caused any error in the shell the words of the snippet have been more or less as key words or built-in functions. I haven't found the `para` function explained on the internet. Also the dot `.` seems to be strange in the expression.

Could anybody explain the syntax of it and tell a web index of all Scheme Lisp functions, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Update: Thanks to user coredump for a clarification on variadic arguments]

You haven't found `para` anywhere, because it is defined there — it is a function definition with a variable number of arguments:

```
(define (para . contents)
    (string-append "<p>" (string-concatenate contents) "</p>"))
```

What this does, is that it defines a function that takes a number of strings as arguments, which are then stored in a list called `contents`, and returns a single string which consists of the HTML p-tag surrounding the content you passed in.

So you can call it like

```
(para "This is a sentence. " "And another one. " "The third one. ")
```

(Note the spaces after the full stops.) And it would return

```
"<p>This is a sentence. And another one. The third one. </p>"
```

As for an index of Scheme functions: Have a look at the [Scheme Standard](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/) (the link is for R5RS).

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated